# PHP - retrieve sub array value by key

Tags: php

Given the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 382
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 509
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 636
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 763
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 890
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id_field] => 1017
        )

)
```

Is there a built in array method which can grab all id_field values?

I can loop over them for sure, but think maybe there is a built in that i cannot see in the manual that already does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.5.0+, you could use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column):

```
$result = array_column($data, 'id_field');
```

If you're running an older PHP version, you can use the [userland implentation](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) of this function (written by the same author who wrote the original `array_column()` function).

However, for simple use-cases, this can be implemented as function using a simple `foreach` loop. This isn't guaranteed to handle all possible cases, but it should be enough for the most part.

```
function array_column2(array $arr, $column) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = $arr[$column];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using array filtering:

```
function id($var){
    return($var['id_field']);
}

print_r(array_filter($arr,"id"));
```

or in PHP 5.4+

```
print_r(array_filter($arr,  function id($var){
    return($var['id_field']);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys) is what you are looking for.

sample from docs:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));

$array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));

$array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
print_r(array_keys($array));
?>
```

and it's output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => color
    [1] => size
)
```