# How to change the array in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I've an SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT test_user_user_id FROM OCN.tests_users WHERE test_user_test_id = 99
$this->mDb->Query( $sql );
$students_data = $this->mDb->FetchArray();
```

I get the array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => b9e6493f9f8599bc5a0a5935275228c2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => 395599c5891c1418357e2efa89bc3e27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => 3255605bb9fd3ecc0295a1bfb3cba147
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => ebe6711fc156b2cc1a33f64f3d86150f
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => 627b9c3f21d93f1e13af076cff20b143
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => 030e96561c01afde1c46384f57cf8749
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [test_user_user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
        )
)
```

Actually I want the array in following format:

```
Array
    (

                [0] => b9e6493f9f8599bc5a0a5935275228c2

                [1] => 395599c5891c1418357e2efa89bc3e27

                [2] => 3255605bb9fd3ecc0295a1bfb3cba147

                [3] => ebe6711fc156b2cc1a33f64f3d86150f

                [4] => 627b9c3f21d93f1e13af076cff20b143

                [5] => 030e96561c01afde1c46384f57cf8749

                [6] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d

    )
```

How to get the array in above format?

Comment: Use `array_column($arr, 'test_user_id');`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21856994/1438393) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$resArray = Array();
foreach($myArr as $_arr)
{
   $resArray[] = $_arr['test_user_user_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
function user_id($e)
{
    return $e['test_user_user_id'];
}

$students_data = array_map('user_id', $students_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array();
$counter = 0; // optional... because by default starting index is 0... however if you want to change the index then use a counter
foreach($students_data as $row) {
    $new_array[$counter] = $row['test_user_user_id'];
    $counter++;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Instead of creating a counter variable, you can simply use the key: `foreach ($students_data as $key => $row) { ... $new_array[$key] ... }` - If the keys are numeric (as they are in this case), you can simply push it using the `[] =` syntax: `$new_array[] = $row['test_user_id']`.

Comment: yes... agreed... by default the starting index is 0...so it will work without the counter as well